# Using angular material in visual studio asp.net application

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, typescript, angular-material

I have a web application that is created with mvc asp.net and angular.js in visual studio..
So I am trying to make a treeview in one of my views
I searched the internet and I found this amazing library [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview)
I saw some examples and when I opened the source. I found that is contained from html css **ts** code...
I am using angular in my application but I don't have any idea about typeScript files or how to use it !!!
Can anyone help me in applying [these examples](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples) into my application and where can I put the .ts scripts ????

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Material will not work with Angular.js, as it is meant for Angular v2+. There is a [material library for Angular.js](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started), but it does not include a tree component.

Comment: I found this library amazing and I want to use it in my project ASAP.
But I have a little issue here..
As mentioned before my project is mvc ASP.Net with angular js..
So I have a shared layout.. and that layout is including angular js v.1.5.8, and this version is on all the pages of my project
when I am trying to use this example https://codepen.io/team/AngularMaterial/pen/RrbXyW
in my project it shows me an error. I searched the error and to solve it I need to include another version of jquery in my page...
So do you have any idea how can I do this.. ??????